# Regex to find multiple instance of a string inside tags

Tags: regex, regular-language

I've this file:

```
BT
abc
def
(xxxx)Tj
ghi
lmn
(yyyy)Tj
ET
AK
abc
def
(wwww)Tj
ghi
lmn
(zzzz)Tj
EK
.....
```

(This is an example of PDF structure).

I want to extract every **(text)Tj** inside **BT->ET** tags.
The output for this example must be:

- *xxxx*
- *yyyy*

(and not also 'wwww' and 'zzzz' because are inside AK->EK tags...)

i write my first regex:

```
(?:^BT$)(:?[\s\S]*?)(^\(.*\)Tj$)(?:[\s\S]*?)(:?^ET$)
```

But this take only first 'xxxx'.
How can i do?

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: i'm testing regex with notepad++, and when this is ok i write in c#

Answer (score 2):

And the happy news is C# would support [`\G` anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). The anchor \G matches at the position where the previous match ended.

```
(?:(?:^|\n)\bBT\b|(?<!^)\G)(?:(?!\bET\b).)*?\(([^)]+)\)Tj(?=\n(?:(?!\bET\b).)*?ET)
```

Just grab the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tU5oL3/4)

Comment: Thanks for this working regex. I've not understand 100% the \G operator. If i have to discard lines with only spaces "(    )Tj"  how can i do?

Comment: @davymartu see https://regex101.com/r/tU5oL3/4 , just change `*` after the negated charcater class to `+`

Comment: you're wonderful but if i've ( '     ')Tj  with a lot of space?

Comment: You're the best! i've tried your final solution with (?!\s+\)) after ([^)]+) but without success...and i'm not understand why

Comment: lookarounds are used for condition checking purposes `(?!\s+\))` chects that there isn't one or more spaces and `)` following the opening `(` paranthesis. If the condition is satisfied, then only it matches `[^)]+` any character but not of `)`, one or more times.